# Is it possible to add duplicates in Set?

Tags: java

Recently I have attend one interview. In my manager round he asked how to make Set to allow duplicate .I told doesn't allow duplicate its not possible .but he is not accepting my answer.Is there any tricky way ??.I have searched in Google I haven't get any proper answer..Please help me

Comment: Well if you write class which will not properly override equals and hashcode methods you can for instance add duplicates to HashSet.

Comment: As Pshemo said, you can do that. But just using a regular HashSet or HashMap, no. I think it may have been a trick question!

Comment: @Pshemo - While your solution will compile, it is still a violation of a declarative contract of the interface.

Comment: @PM77-1 And that problem interviewer could want to talk about. I am not saying that I am sure of it, but it is possibility...

Comment: Basically it boils down to a manager's definition of a `Set`. Is it any class that implements the interface or only those that implement it properly?

Comment: @Pshemo That still wouldn't add duplicates, because they would be different objects.

Comment: The manager was wrong. A *set* is not allowed to contain duplicates. A *bag* may. However, the Java `Set` is just an interface, so you *could* (but shouldn't) create your own implementation that violates the contract of the API, as @PM77-1 alluded to.

Comment: @andreas thanks for the comment.but I have argued too.even though he is not accepting my answers.for your information I have voted for you

Comment: Maybe he should read up on bags/multisets, like on Wikipedia: [Multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset): "a multiset (or bag) is a generalization of the concept of a set that, **unlike a set**, allows multiple instances of the multiset's elements.". Or follow the link to the [computer related article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28abstract_data_type%29#Multiset), which says "multiset or bag, which is similar to a set **but allows** repeated ("equal") values (**duplicates**)." Back up top it defines set as "no repeated values".

Comment: Alternate interpretation: In his loose use of the word "set", a `List` is a set (collection) that allows duplicates.

Comment: If you were interviewing for a job, and that manager would be your boss, maybe you should reconsider, because working for a [PHB](http://dilbert.wikia.com/wiki/Pointy-Haired_Boss) like that is not good.

Comment: Ha ha ..you are right.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on what kind of set you are using.

### Scenario for HashSet

HashSet is storing its element in buckets which are grouping elements with similar hashcodes (each bucket stores elements which give same result for formula `objectHashCode%numberOfBuckets`). For instance if there will be two buckets, one will store elements with odd hashes, and one with even hashes. Also this buckets doesn't have access to other buckets (and they shouldn't since equal objects should have same hash, so should be placed in same bucket)

Lets say we have class which `hashcode` is calculated using mutable field

```
class SomeClass{

    private int x;  

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        SomeClass other = (SomeClass) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    //getters, setters, constructor, toString
}
```

If we add into `HashSet` object with hashcode `1` it will end up in first bucket. But if we edit this object so it will have hash `2` and try to add it to set, we will be able to do so, because it will end up in second bucket which doesn't check if object is in other buckets (which is why HashSets are so fast).

Demo:

```
Set<SomeClass> set = new HashSet<>();

SomeClass v = new SomeClass(1);
set.add(v);

v.setX(2);
set.add(v);

System.out.println(set);
```

Output:

```
[Value [x=2], Value [x=2]]
```

---

This shows why we should not modify objects after placing them into set. Or why we should prefer to chose constant fields over mutable fields while implementing hashcode method. Or why immutable classes are safer than mutable ones.

Comment: Simply, you are just overriding equals() in object to allow duplicates in the Set. If I say so, is it correct?

Comment: @JudeNiroshan Not quite. Main problem in this example is hashcode method, which doesn't guarantee that one object will always return same value.

Answer (score 0):

To build a set that can hold duplicates (=a multiset by definition) from a set you could store elements with counters. I think this is the only "sane" meaning one could find in this question (some others are ruled out in the comments above already). It's still interesting because the tricky part is to make sure element matching still works. So in Java it would be something along these lines:

```
class MultiSet<T> {
  private Set<CountingContainer<T>> set = new HashSet<T>();

  public void add(T value) {
    CountingContainer<T> container = new CountingContainer<T>(value); 
    CountingContainer<T> existing = set.get(container);
    if (existing == null) {
      set.add(container);
    } else {
      existing.count++;
    }
  }

  public int getCount(T value) {
    CountingContainer<T> container = new CountingContainer<T>(value); 
    CountingContainer<T> existing = set.get(container);
    return existing == null ? 0 : existing.count;
  }

  private static class CountingContainer<T> {
    int count;
    T value;
    private CountingContainer(T value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
      return value.hashCode();
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      return (o instanceof CountingContainer) 
          && value.equals(((CountingContainer) o).value);
    }
  }
```

A "real" Java MultiSet implementation would just use a Map to map elements to counts though.

Comment: How does it answer OP's question?

Comment: No this is not the answer what I want. he asked specifically Set not MultiSet.

Comment: Well a Set that allows the same time multiple times is by definition a MultiSet. So there are two options: It's a trick question, in which case the answer is no, or the interviewer wants to see an implementation of a MultiSet based on a Set. And the trick question was apparently ruled out by the interviewer already if I understand the description correctly...

Comment: My concern is tricky question.I don't think he is genius than SO legend's

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird question so my answer is also a bit weird but I have seen people doing this kind of mistake often. In my program I have overridden equals and hashCode to correctly. Whereas my compareTo method is written to sort Employees as per there names.

And we are using a TreeSet here but as TreeSet uses compareTo not equals to mark Object duplicate we can see we have 3 object in output instead of one.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    final class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{
        private int id;
        private String name;

        public Employee(int id, String name) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + id;
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Employee other = (Employee) obj;
            if (id != other.id)
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Employee o) {
            return name.compareTo(o.name);
        }


    }

    Set<Employee> empSet = new TreeSet<>();
    empSet.add(new Employee(1,"Adam"));
    empSet.add(new Employee(1,"John"));
    empSet.add(new Employee(1,"Smith"));

    System.out.println(empSet.size());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the set collection not permit values duplicate, the list permit duplicated values
and map are key and value